# Tensorflow dataset not saved in multiple shards

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I want to use the tensorflow dataset saving and loading functions but I am not sure to understand the sharding method.

The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#save) indicates :

> The saved dataset is saved in multiple file "shards". By default, the dataset output is divided to shards in a round-robin fashion but custom sharding can be specified via the shard_func function.

But when I save a dataset through the save function, it seems that only one huge shard is generated.

```
import tempfile
import tensorflow as tf

path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), "saved_data")
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(10**8)

dataset.save(path)
```

[generated dataset screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2Qkh.png)

Am I missing something ?

I use Tensorflow 2.10.0 and Python 3.9.7

Comment: Did you resolve? I'm getting one big 9.5GB shard ...

Comment: Unfortunately I got no answer and the saving method still creates one big file with newer TF versions.